# Why my tf.profiler.Profiler complains "Found accelerator operation but misses accelerator stream stats"

Tags: python, tensorflow, profiler

I'm using the [tf.profiler.Profiler](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/profiler/Profiler#profile_name_scope) trying to get some insight of my model and hopefully to improve its performance. But both of `profiler.profile_operations(options=opts)` and `profiler.profile_name_scope(options)`'s output is missing the GPU timing stats.

Here is some excerpt of the operation profile's output:

```
Found accelerator operation but misses accelerator stream stats!

It's likely a gpu tracing issue rather than tf-profiler issue.
If you found your operation missing accelerator time, consider filing a bug to xprof-dev@!


Doc:
op: The nodes are operation kernel type, such as MatMul, Conv2D. Graph nodes belonging to the same type are aggregated together.
requested bytes: The memory requested by the operation, accumulatively.
total execution time: Sum of accelerator execution time and cpu execution time.
cpu execution time: The time from the start to the end of the operation. It's the sum of actual cpu run time plus the time that it spends waiting if part of computation is launched asynchronously.
accelerator execution time: Time spent executing on the accelerator. This is normally measured by the actual hardware library.

Profile:
node name | requested bytes | total execution time | accelerator execution time | cpu execution time
TensorArrayScatterV3           50.66MB (100.00%, 6.21%),      3.49sec (100.00%, 39.64%),             0us (0.00%, 0.00%),      3.49sec (100.00%, 39.64%)
LogicalAnd                            0B (0.00%, 0.00%),       1.86sec (60.36%, 21.11%),             0us (0.00%, 0.00%),       1.86sec (60.36%, 21.11%)
Merge                          690.95KB (93.79%, 0.08%),       675.01ms (39.25%, 7.66%),             0us (0.00%, 0.00%),       675.01ms (39.25%, 7.66%)
TensorArrayReadV3                     0B (0.00%, 0.00%),       487.78ms (31.58%, 5.54%),             0us (0.00%, 0.00%),       487.78ms (31.58%, 5.54%)
Less                            22.08MB (93.70%, 2.71%),       397.04ms (26.05%, 4.51%),             0us (0.00%, 0.00%),       397.04ms (26.05%, 4.51%)
TensorArrayWriteV3                    0B (0.00%, 0.00%),       336.87ms (21.54%, 3.82%),             0us (0.00%, 0.00%),       336.87ms (21.54%, 3.82%)
Switch                                0B (0.00%, 0.00%),       333.95ms (17.71%, 3.79%),             0us (0.00%, 0.00%),       333.95ms (17.71%, 3.79%)
Add                              1.11KB (90.99%, 0.00%),       302.02ms (13.92%, 3.43%),             0us (0.00%, 0.00%),       302.02ms (13.92%, 3.43%)
NextIteration                         0B (0.00%, 0.00%),       294.50ms (10.49%, 3.34%),             0us (0.00%, 0.00%),       294.50ms (10.49%, 3.34%)
...
...
```

All the stats in the `accelerator execution time` column is zero.

Comment: I have the exact same issue! I feel like the profiler is very scarcely documented.

Comment: This looks like a bug, it would help to file a github issue on TensorFlow with a reproducible example.